# Snowflake & NodeJS - Connection options must be specified

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with NodeJs to insert data into Snowflake, but I'm facing the error:

> Error [MissingParameterError]: Connection options must be specified.

Here's my simplified code:

```js
import * as snowflake from 'snowflake-sdk';
import { Config } from "./config";

const config1 = {
    account:"xxx.eu-west-1",
    username:"xxxx",
    password:"xxxx",
    authenticator:"SNOWFLAKE",
    clientSessionKeepAlive:true,
    warehouse:"xxxxx",
    database:"xxxx",
    schema:"xxxx"
}

export class InjectSF {

    public connectionpoolsf: snowflake.createConnection;

    constructor() {
      this.connectionpoolsf = new snowflake.createConnection;
        
    }

    public init = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.configsf.initConfig()
                .then(() => {
                    this.connectionpoolsf = new snowflake.createConnection(config1);
                    this.connectionpoolsf.connect( 
                        function(err, conn) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
                                } 
                            else {
                                console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
                                }
                            }
                        );
                })
                .catch((err) => reject(err));
        });
    }

.... other functions ...

    public start = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.init()
                .then(() => this.readDir())
                .then((filenames) => this.readFiles(filenames))
                .then((resultFile) => this.createTable(resultFile))
                .then(() => resolve())
                .catch((err) => reject(err));

        });
    };

}

try {
    const injectSF = new InjectSF();
    injectSF.start()
        .then(() => 'Insert Ok!')
        .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
} catch (err) {
   throw err;
}
```

In reality, I have a separated config file for the Snowflake connection parameters because I retrieve the password from AWS Secret Manager, but even if I just write my config parameters like that with everything, I keep getting the error. I don't understand what parameter/option I am missing.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const connect = connection => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.connect(
    function (err, conn) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
        reject(new Error(err.message));
      } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake');
        resolve(conn);
      }
    }
  );
});

async function main () {
 
  const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
    account: '<account>',
    username: '<user>',
    password: '<pass>',
    warehouse: '<wh>',
    database: '<db>',
    schema: '<sch>',
    role: '<role>'
  });
 
  await connect(connection);
...
}
```